# How to replace Entry Event in journey builder

Tags: journeybuilder

In the past, when i created journeys, i used the Entry Event source, with an automation in Automation studio to launch the journey when an update of the Data Extension appears.

With the last release, i can't now use Entry Event source, and the 'Help' tell me to use Audience source : Email studio Audience. 
Could you tell me : if i schedule the journey to run every day, does it update each time the data extension ? Or do i still need to use an automation before to update the audience ?
Thanks a lot